# How to pass in a new column name within an R function

Tags: r, function, indexing

I have searched many questions but can't get any of their solutions to work in my scenario. I'm sure it's easy though! I have a toy dataset (but don't know how to upload it).

I have a large (and `tidy`) dataset where I want to count across various columns how many are not NA, per row. I want to put that count into a new column, and name that new column. I index the count by finding the start and end columns through `which` and then use `rowSums` to count. That works fine.

BUT, I cannot get it to make the new column with the newvarname I want. As I will be repeating this function many time, I need the newvarname to change.

```
count.non.na.cols <- function(x, qstartvar, qendvar, newvarname) {
    qstart <- which(names(x) == qstartvar)
    qend <- which(names(x) == qendvar)
    x[[newvarname]] <- rowSums(!is.na(data1xqstart:qend]))
    x
    }

count.non.na.cols(x = data1, qstartvar = "3-Acquiring.equipment.and.becoming.operational", 
              qendvar = "3-Other:", newvarname = "NumLim2")
```

I don't get any errors. I just don't get the new column in data1. Please help.
(I have tried `rename`, `colnames`, and `mutate`.)

Comment: Your function is not returning the modified `data1`. Make just `data1` the last line of the function.

Comment: Even that doesn't work. It prints to my console, but not to my dataset.           data1 <- data1 also doesn't work

Comment: Your scope is broken. When you do a simple assignment using `<-`, R is smartly making a copy of the `data1` object that is somewhere outside of the function. That copy is properly updated. And in this code example, all your function is currently returning is the vector of `rowSums(...)`. I suggest you make `data1` an argument of the function, best as the first argument, i.e., `function(x, qstartvar, qendvar, newvarname) { ... x[[newvarname]] <- rowSums(...) ; x ; }`

Comment: I think that's my problem, but it still isn't available. The function works, in that it runs `rowSums` and with `x`, or even `return(x)`, it prints in my console. But when I click on the actual data1 file the new column isn't there, and when (out of the function) I type data1$newvarname, I get `NULL`.

Comment: My colleague noticed my very stupid miss. I needed to SAVE the data.        `data1 <- count.non.na.cols(x = data1, ...)`